# How to insert in shell script from java index

Tags: java, shell

I am using Java to run a sh file.

However, the question is how to put Java's variables into a sh variable while executing the sh file for Eclipse.

I am using eclipse.

Here is my code

```
test.sh
#!/bin/sh
docker run -it --name $1 ubuntu:16.04
exit 0
```

In java

```
public static void makeContainer() throws Exception {
    //String makecontainer = "/usr/local/bin/docker run --name "+fileName+" ubuntu:16.04";

    String[] command = { "/bin/sh","/Users/keomgong1/Desktop/test.sh", fileName };
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    process.getInputStream();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

}
```

I want $1 as filename but it is not running as expected.

filename is java string index.

What's wrong?

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument after the script name is the program name (`$0`), instead of the first positional parameter (`$1`).

You can add a dummy filename for `$0` and then your next parameter will be `$1`:

```
String[] command = { "/bin/sh","/Users/keomgong1/Desktop/test.sh", "_", fileName };
```

However, it is better to run the script directly instead of with `/bin/sh`:

```
String[] command = { "/Users/keomgong1/Desktop/test.sh", fileName };
```

This requires `test.sh` to have a shebang (first line is `#!/bin/sh`) and execute permissions (`chmod +x /Users/keomgong1/Desktop/test.sh`).